# Closed sets in $\mathbb{P}^1\times\cdots\times\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{P}^1\times\cdots\times\mathbb{P}^1$ have the topology given by the Segre embedding. If a closed set in $\mathbb{P}^1\times\cdots\times\mathbb{P}^1$ has the form $A\times\cdots\times A$ for some proper subset $A\subset\mathbb{P}^1$, is $A$ necessarily finite?

Comment: Yes. You are taking a product of finote sets...

Comment: Silly comment- $A$ could be all of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Sure, I mean $A$ proper, I edited the question. @MoarCake559 do you know why?

Comment: Do you now Zariski topology of $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Yes @Armandoj18eos  , closed proper subsets of $\mathbb{P}^1$ are finite in the Zariski topology, but that doesn't a priori answer my question because the topology of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\cdots\times\mathbb{P}^1$ is not the product topology

Comment: Yes, it is true! Do you remember that the projections $pr_i$ of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\dots\times\mathbb{P}^1$ onto $\mathbb{P}^1$'s are closed?

Comment: Ok, I didn't actually :p thank you

Comment: While it is important to know the projections are proper, the result here is a bit simpler. Let $p\in A$ (clearly, we may assume $A\neq\emptyset$) and then $\mathbb{P}^1\times\{p\}\times\cdots\times\{p\}$ is a closed subset and thus its intersection with $A\times\cdots \times A$. This is just $A\times\{p\}\times \cdots\times\{p\}$. which you can see is essentially $A\subset\mathbb{P}^1$.